# Проблема с циклом заполнения таблицы в docx

Tags: python, for

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема:
хочу в docx вставить таблицу
Вот такой код:

```
table = doc.add_table(rows = len(df_consumer_type), cols = len(df_consumer_type.columns))
# применяем стиль для таблицы
table.style = 'Table Grid'
# заполняем таблицу данными
for i in range(len(df_consumer_type)):
    for j in range(len(df_consumer_type.columns)):
        # получаем ячейку таблицы
        cell = table.cell(i, j)
        # записываем в ячейку данные
        meaning = df_consumer_type[df_consumer_type.columns[j]].iloc[i]
        cell.text = meaning
```

вылетает ошибка 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
Не могу понять почему... Вроде бы везде все итерируемое...

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: На самом деле я решил проблему. оказывается дело именно в том, что это таблица docx. В ячейки этой таблицы нельзя вписать int или float. Только строку... как только внес это исправление - все чудесно заработало